# Deserialize object using JSON.NET without the need for a container

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using JSON.NET to deseralize JSON strings that I receive from a service to my business objects.

I have a nice Service pattern that parses all my JSON strings from a given REST URL to an object as follows:

```
private async Task<T> LoadJSONToObject<T>(string url)
{
    //get data
    var json = await GetResultStringAsync(url);

    //deserialize it
    var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    return results;
}
```

The challenge that I am having is how do I use the above pattern with collections without creating a "container" class.

For example, if I am getting the following JSON back:

```
{
    "Properties": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Property Name A",
            "address": "Address A, City, Country",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Property Name B",
            "address": "Address B, City, Country",
        }
    ]
}
```

And my business entity is as follows:

```
public class Property
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("address")]
    public string Address{ get; set; }

}
```

I would like to simply invoke my above method by calling:

```
LoadJSONToObject<List<Property>>("http://www.myapi.com/properties");
```

The above fails because JSON.NET is expecting a container object instead. Something like:

```
public class PropertyList 
{
    [JsonProperty("Properties")]
    public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

I think it's an overkill to create such a container and want to see if there is an elegant solution to do the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that if you rewrite your `LoadJSONToObject` like this:

```
private async Task<T> LoadJSONToObject<T>(string url, string rootProperty)
{
    //get data
    var json = await GetResultStringAsync(url);

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rootProperty))
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);

    var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

    var parsedJson = jObject[rootProperty].ToString();

    //deserialize it
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(parsedJson);
}
```

Your method call should be

```
LoadJSONToObject<List<Property>>("http://www.myapi.com/properties", "Properties");
```